# how long does an OTA update normally take?

Tags: updates, custom-roms, device-firmware, ota-update

I am using the Oxygen ROM on my LG P500 (Optimus One) and I just did an OTA Update and the ohone restarted and it has been in a flashing mode every since, the bar is at about 15% for the past 30 minutes so I was wondering if there is a problem or the firmware upgrade normally takes a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The progress bar being stuck for a while is not unusual as progress bars are fairly difficult to get right. An update taking more than half an hour, on the other hand, doesn't sound right to me. Of course your phone could simply be slower at this task than mine.

Comment: Yeah it was a bit slow but eventually it pulled through thanks for your answer.